# A general word for leg wear?

Tags: word-choice

How do you call the wear for legs in general? That which includes trousers, breeches, leggings, jeans etc? Or do you use "trousers" as this general word? How then you call the trousers proper (those from a modern business suite for example)?

Comment: In the U.S., the general word would probably be _pants_.

Comment: What about "bottom-half clothing"? - Unlikely to be any good, but in the UK we do refer to the "bottom half" when in doubt as to the appropriate word for an item of clothing. E.g. "Did you see what she had on her bottom half?"

Comment: @JMB bottom-half will include a skirt but I am referring to the wear that covers the both legs separately.

Comment: Fair enough. I imagine @J.R. has nailed it for the US side of things, and you yourself said "trousers" which strikes me as the best for the UK.

Comment: @JMB so how would you call the trousers proper then? "Classic trousers?"

Comment: I would say "suit trousers".

Comment: @JMB classic trousers may not be part of a suite.

Comment: Well no, but we're entering dangerous territory here. I would say "smart" or "formal" to describe trousers that are not jeans and are not scruffy, and may or may not be part of a suit.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure such a hypernym exists:

- *[trousers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trousers)* denotes clothing that covers the all or most of both legs separately. Trousers don't usually go above the waist.
- *[skirts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skirts)/[dresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dress)/[robes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robe)* denotes clothing that covers both legs together. (*Kilts* refer specifically to skirts for men.)
  *Robes/dresses* generally refer to clothing that covers the torso as well as the legs, but *skirts* and *kilts* generally don't.
- *[shorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shorts)* denotes clothing that covers both legs separately, from the knees (or thereabouts) up.
- *legwear* is a term that I've not heard in reference to the above, but it invokes *pantyhose* or *hosiery* for me (and indeed, Wikipedia redirects *legwear* to *hosiery*).
  It seems to be the case that it refers only to clothing that covers only the legs and feet.

Interestingly, we have the hypernym *tops* to refer to clothing that covers the torso, and with that I have the intuition that usage skews toward describing the clothing of this type worn by women - men tend to refer to all *tops* by their more specific meronym.
It's been suggested that *bottoms* is a possible hypernym that includes all of the above clothing, but I'm not entirely sure about this one - while it's intuitively the opposite of *tops*, it may only work in proximity to *tops*, for instance:

> Our choir performs in white tops and black bottoms

but not

> They wear woollen bottoms

This second example sounds odd to me, and it wouldn't be immediately apparent that it meant trousers/skirts. My initial reaction is that they wear some kind of woollen covering around their waist/hip/buttocks, like extremely short pants.

---

**Short answer:** No. Unfortunately, *trousers* refers to clothing that covers all or most of both legs separately, and it excludes some clothing included by *shorts*. You'd probably need to use both, and I'm *not* sure whether *leggings* are covered by it, either - you might need to say *trousers, shorts and leggings*, I'm afraid.

Comment: I do not ask for skirts. Is the trousers the general word for wear that covers the legs separately?

Comment: @Anixx unfortunately, _trousers_ refers to clothing that covers all or most of both legs separately, and it excludes some clothing included by _shorts_. You'd probably need to use both, and I'm _not_ sure whether _leggings_ are covered by it, either - you might need to say _trousers, shorts and leggings_, I'm afraid.

Comment: Are tights included here?

Comment: @Anixx I would say _no_, but they would be covered by leggings.

Comment: What about the wear that covers the both legs that was used by ancient peoples, for example, the ones from skin or fur. Should it also be called "trousers"?

Comment: @Anixx there's no real limit on the source of these terms - it depends on how much of the body it covers. Also, in a technical field, you may refer to it by the contemporary term. _Robes_ seems most appropriate, but it would depend. I've updated my answer to reflect some of the conditions.

Comment: Informally you can say 'bottom(s)'. Our choir performs in white tops and black bottoms (which means long skirts for the women).